# AT&T's SMTP to SMS increments sender address

Tags: smtp, sms

I have a service that delivers updates to users through various carriers SMTP APIs, for example for Sprint we e-mail `1123456789@messaging.sprintpcs.com` and then the owner of the number `1123456789` receives an SMS message which is displayed as being from our e-mail address, for example `updates@example.com`, the user is then able to reply to this and we receive over SMTP their response.

However, when it comes to AT&T when the user receives our messages, the from address is some number such as `180000001`, which increments for each message. As you can imagine, if we send the user 100 updates throughout the week, that is 100 different senders AT&T users see in their phone, which really clogs up their messaging lists.

Is there a way to specify to AT&T a correct from address to display? All of the information I could find from AT&T is [here](http://www.att.com/esupport/article.jsp?sid=KB92125).(I've tested this on Sprint, MetroPCS and T-Mobile and they handle it properly)

Also, with AT&T if the user replies to any of the messages that appears in their phone, even though they have 100 different sender addresses they are all received by our `updates@example.com` e-mail address successfully.

Comment: To be honest I'm not 100% sure if superuser is the right place for this question, but I couldn't think of any other stackexchange site that was appropriate.

Comment: Have you considered sending SMS messages directly/yourself?

Comment: No, 100 a week was just the example. Realistically we send between 1000-5000 a week to all users, and the messages have to be delivered instantly when triggered by user's events. However, for one single AT&T it is perfectly realistic to say they may receive only 100 in a week.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like they're translating, especially if responses are correctly routed. Not sure there's anything you can do if its something at&t is doing on the backend

Comment: Since AT&T have e-mail aliases for people on their network I was hoping that maybe there was a way tor me to pass something to them with my "alias" or name to display.

Comment: you can but they don't have to actually display it

Comment: Well, yes, and evidently they don't have to display the from address either. But if there was an option like that I'd give it a go.

Comment: There isn't that I'm aware of from a client point of view.. but I may be wrong.